# I want to create a website where one person have only one account. But how I will do it if a person uses VPN or proxy?

Tags: php

I want to create a website where one person can have only one account. But how I will do it if a person uses VPN or proxy?

Comment: How were you going to enforce one account per person even if they *weren't* using a VPN or proxy?

Answer (score 0):

While there is no solution that truly ensures someone will have only one account, you can make it much more difficult for someone to have multiple accounts by enforcing a "real name" and "aged account" requirement.

The easiest way to do this is:

1. Implement Facebook Login
   (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web) as your
   login.
2. Get the user's friend count
   (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#total_friend_count)
   and make sure it is sufficiently large (say 25 friends) that they
   didn't just set up the account.